# spring-orm-4.2.6 incompatible to hibernate-orm-5.2.0

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-orm

Latest Hibernate ORM release (5.2.0) renders Spring ORM (4.2.6, latest) incompatible because Hibernate had to rename its Session.getFlushMode to Session.getHibernateFlushMode resulting in this NoSuchMethodError:

> Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.hibernate.Session.getFlushMode()Lorg/hibernate/FlushMode;     at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.prepareFlushMode(HibernateJpaDialect.java:187)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.prepareTransaction(HibernateJpaDialect.java:182)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.prepareTransaction(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:321)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.doGetTransactionalEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:293)

When will Spring provide a HibernateJpaDialect compatible with Hibernate 5.2.0?

Bye

Comment: Since neither Spring nor Hibernate use bugtracking on github I decided to post it here hoping that some responsible persons will read it. I am not willing to register at Jira, sorry.

Comment: @NeilStockton Sorry! My bad

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spring Framework 4.3.0 will include support for Hibernate 5.2. See https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-14327