# Spring 4.3.2 & hibernate 5.2.1 : NosuchMethod error

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, pom.xml

So I have this pom.xml :

```
<dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.0.Alpha1</version>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.37</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>1.10.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

And I still get this error :

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.Session.getFlushMode()Lorg/hibernate/FlushMode;
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.prepareFlushMode(HibernateJpaDialect.java:187)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.beginTransaction(HibernateJpaDialect.java:173)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:380)
... 52 common frames omitted
```

I searched [here](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-14327) and it's marked as resolved. Maybe it's not !

Any solutions ?
Thanks

Comment: it s just version compatibility problem ... see this question it might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37631150/hibernatetemplate-is-throwing-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-org-hibernate-session

Comment: yeah I know and As indicated it's resolved in spring 4.3 version but it seems not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone got the same problem :

the problem was that the jars in **spring-data-jpa** was ''***OLD***'' so you need to update it yourself to the last version wich is **4.2.3** (At my response Time) or just excluded in your *POM.XML*