# Spring and hibernate integration Could not open JPA

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, spring-mvc

I am currently developing a java/jee app using spring as framework and hibernate as orm.I am using the generic dao design pattern.I want to add a courrier Object to the db but i don't know why i got this error.

this is my log

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.Session.getFlushMode()Lorg/hibernate/FlushMode;
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:431)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:447)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:277)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:656)
    at biz.picosoft.daoImpl.CourrierDaoImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$61c46376.insert(<generated>)
    at biz.picosoft.mains.TestHibernate.main(TestHibernate.java:26)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.Session.getFlushMode()Lorg/hibernate/FlushMode;
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.prepareFlushMode(HibernateJpaDialect.java:176)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.beginTransaction(HibernateJpaDialect.java:162)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:380)
    ... 8 more
```

this is my context

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="biz.picosoft.entity" />

        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                <property name="generateDdl" value="true"></property>
                <property name="showSql" value="true"></property>

            </bean>
        </property>

    </bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="biz.picosoft" />
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mailmanager" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="" />
        <property name="defaultAutoCommit" value="true" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="contactDaoImpl" class="biz.picosoft.daoImpl.ContacteDaoImpl" />
    <bean id="SociétéDaoImpl" class="biz.picosoft.daoImpl.SociétéDaoImpl" />

    <bean id="sociétéDaoImpl" class="biz.picosoft.daoImpl.SociétéDaoImpl" />
    <bean id="courrierDaoImpl" class="biz.picosoft.daoImpl.CourrierDaoImpl"></bean>
    <!-- enable the configuration of transactional behavior based on annotations -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
    <tx:annotation-driven proxy-target-class="true" />

</beans>
```

this is my pom

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>BackEndFinalVersion</groupId>
    <artifactId>BackEndFinalVersion</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.alfresco.cmis.client/alfresco-opencmis-extension -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.alfresco.cmis.client</groupId>
            <artifactId>alfresco-opencmis-extension</artifactId>
            <version>0.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.25</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-ldap</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>




        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ldap</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ldap-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.activiti</groupId>
            <artifactId>activiti-ldap</artifactId>
            <version>5.17.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.168</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.activiti</groupId>
            <artifactId>activiti-spring</artifactId>
            <version>5.22.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.8</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.8</version>
        </dependency>





        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.4</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.activiti</groupId>
            <artifactId>activiti-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.22.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.168</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.193</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.7.RELEASE</version>

        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.activiti</groupId>
            <artifactId>activiti-spring</artifactId>
            <version>5.22.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.6</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

this is my generic daoImpl

```
package biz.picosoft.daoImpl;

import java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.Query;

import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import biz.picosoft.dao.GenericDao;



@Transactional(readOnly = false)
public class GenericDaoImp<T> implements GenericDao<T> {
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    protected Class<T> daoType;

    public GenericDaoImp() {
        Type t = getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
        ParameterizedType pt = (ParameterizedType) t;
        daoType = (Class) pt.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    }

    public EntityManager getEm() {
        return em;
    }

    public void setEm(EntityManager em) {
        this.em = em;
    }

    public Class<T> getDaoType() {
        return daoType;
    }

    public void setDaoType(Class<T> daoType) {
        this.daoType = daoType;
    }

    public void insert(T t) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        em.persist(t);

    }

    public void update(T t) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        em.merge(t);
    }

    public void delete(T t) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Object managed = em.merge(t);
        em.remove(managed);
    }

    public T findById(Class<T> t, String id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return em.find(daoType, id);
    }

    public List<T> findAll() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT e FROM " + daoType.getName() + " e");
        return (List<T>) query.getResultList();
    }

}
```

my entity

```
   package biz.picosoft.entity;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Collection;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;

@Entity
public class Société implements Serializable {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "idSociété")
    int idSociété;
    @Column(name = "nom")
    String nom;
    @Column(name = "email")
    String email;
    @Column(name = "télèphone")
    String télèphone;
    @Column(name = "adress")
    String adress;
    @OneToMany
    private Collection<Contacte> contacts;

     public Société(String nom, String email, String télèphone, String adress) {
        super();
        this.nom = nom;
        this.email = email;
        this.télèphone = télèphone;
        this.adress = adress;
    }



    public Société() {
        super();
    }



    public int getIdSociété() {
        return idSociété;
    }

    public void setIdSociété(int idSociété) {
        this.idSociété = idSociété;
    }

    public String getNom() {
        return nom;
    }

    public void setNom(String nom) {
        this.nom = nom;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getTélèphone() {
        return télèphone;
    }

    public void setTélèphone(String télèphone) {
        this.télèphone = télèphone;
    }

    public String getAdress() {
        return adress;
    }

    public void setAdress(String adress) {
        this.adress = adress;
    }

    public Collection<Contacte> getContacts() {
        return contacts;
    }



    public void setContacts(Collection<Contacte> contacts) {
        this.contacts = contacts;
    }



    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + idSociété;
        return result;
    }



    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Société other = (Société) obj;
        if (idSociété != other.idSociété)
            return false;
        return true;
    } 

}
```

my main

```
package biz.picosoft.mains;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

import biz.picosoft.dao.ContacteDao;
import biz.picosoft.daoImpl.ContacteDaoImpl;
import biz.picosoft.daoImpl.SociétéDaoImpl;
import biz.picosoft.entity.Contacte;
import biz.picosoft.entity.Société;

public class TestDaoS {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Société société=new Société("pico", "pico@gmail.com", "74255546", "el ghazella");

        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
        SociétéDaoImpl sociétéDao=(SociétéDaoImpl) context.getBean("sociétéDaoImpl");
        //ContacteDaoImpl contacteDaoImpl = (ContacteDaoImpl) context.getBean("contactDaoImpl");
        sociétéDao.insert(société);
        Contacte contacte=new Contacte("imed", "imed@pico.biz", "7424554", "ghazella", société);
        Contacte contacte2=new Contacte("med", "med@pico.biz", "7424554", "ghazella", société);


        //contacteDaoImpl.insert(contacte);
        //contacteDaoImpl.insert(contacte2);

        System.out.println("list contacts"+sociétéDao.findAll().get(0).getContacts());
                }

}
```

Comment: Have you looked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37651837/integrate-hibernate-5-2-with-spring-framework-4-x?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Integrate Hibernate 5.2 with Spring framework 4.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37651837/integrate-hibernate-5-2-with-spring-framework-4-x)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a common issue with `Spring 4.2` and `Hibernate 5.2` integration, because `Spring 4.2` version supports only `Hibernate` versions up to `5.1`.

There's even a Bug reported for this issue in the Spring community, you can check it :

[**Support for Hibernate ORM 5.2**](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-14327), which is claiming that:

> Hibernate ORM `5.2` got released just in time for Spring Framework `4.3`. Let's do everything we can to support it right away, in particular upgrading our `spring-orm-hibernate5` build to `5.2` while retaining compatbility with `5.0` and `5.1`.

For further details you can check the following posts too:

- [Integrate Hibernate 5.2 with Spring framework 4.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37651837/integrate-hibernate-5-2-with-spring-framework-4-x)
- [HibernateTemplate is throwing java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.Session.getFlushMode() -- Spring4.2.6, Hibernate5.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37631150/hibernatetemplate-is-throwing-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-org-hibernate-session)