# Spring 4.3.0.RELEASE + Hibernate 5.2.0.Final + JPA Repository

Tags: java, xml, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have this Error while trying to work with Spring JPA:

> Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.Session.getFlushMode()Lorg/hibernate/FlushMode;

** Update: Full Stack trace

**It works in the same configuration in diffrent project**

What could be the reason?
I`m using Java 1.8 & Dynamic Web Application 3.1 (As the parallel project that works)

pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>Test</groupId>
    <artifactId>Test</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                    <webXml>WebContent\WEB-INF\web.xml</webXml>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>org.test.int1.Main</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.0.RELEASE</version>
            <exclusions>
            <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                 </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.0.Alpha1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- AspectJ -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.21</version>
        </dependency>
            <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.21</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.21</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Apache Commons DBCP -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Javax -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Servlet -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Full Error:

```
[16/08/16 10:41:57:057 IDT]  INFO web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain: Creating filter chain: org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AnyRequestMatcher@1, [org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@2b00cbc, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@1e44b04e, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@46828666, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@7d5376a4, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@7f04505e, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@44f95930, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter@161a567f, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@709ae44e, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@2d41cca3, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@23ff20e2, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@6792334c, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@408d1364, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@638afb02]
[16/08/16 10:41:57:057 IDT]  INFO http.DefaultFilterChainValidator: Checking whether login URL '/login' is accessible with your configuration
[16/08/16 10:41:57:057 IDT]  INFO startup.StartupDbDataInit: -------------------------------------------------------
[16/08/16 10:41:57:057 IDT]  INFO startup.StartupDbDataInit:          StartupDbDataInit Working - Starting...       
[16/08/16 10:41:57:057 IDT]  INFO startup.StartupDbDataInit: -------------------------------------------------------
[16/08/16 10:41:57:057 IDT] DEBUG internal.TransactionImpl: begin
[16/08/16 10:41:57:057 IDT] DEBUG internal.TransactionImpl: rolling back
[16/08/16 10:41:57:057 IDT] DEBUG internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl: Initiating JDBC connection release from afterTransaction
[16/08/16 10:41:57:057 IDT] DEBUG internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl: Initiating JDBC connection release from afterTransaction
[16/08/16 10:41:57:057 IDT]  INFO startup.StartupDbDataInit: StartupDbDataInit Failed!!!!!, Details=>>> Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.Session.getFlushMode()Lorg/hibernate/FlushMode;
[16/08/16 10:41:57:057 IDT]  WARN support.XmlWebApplicationContext: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'startupDbDataInit': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.Session.getFlushMode()Lorg/hibernate/FlushMode;
[16/08/16 10:41:57:057 IDT]  INFO jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean: Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
[16/08/16 10:41:57:057 IDT] DEBUG internal.SessionFactoryImpl: HHH000031: Closing
[16/08/16 10:41:57:057 IDT] DEBUG spi.CascadeStyles: External cascade style regsitration [persist : STYLE_PERSIST] overrode base registration [STYLE_PERSIST_SKIPLAZY]
[16/08/16 10:41:57:057 IDT] DEBUG internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl: Implicitly destroying ServiceRegistry on de-registration of all child ServiceRegistries
[16/08/16 10:41:57:057 IDT] DEBUG internal.BootstrapServiceRegistryImpl: Implicitly destroying Boot-strap registry on de-registration of all child ServiceRegistries
[16/08/16 10:41:57:057 IDT] ERROR context.ContextLoader: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'startupDbDataInit': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.Session.getFlushMode()Lorg/hibernate/FlushMode;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:136)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:408)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1570)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:775)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:444)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:326)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4842)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5303)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.reload(StandardContext.java:3858)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader.backgroundProcess(WebappLoader.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.backgroundProcess(StandardContext.java:5660)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1376)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1380)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1380)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1348)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.Session.getFlushMode()Lorg/hibernate/FlushMode;
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:431)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:427)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:276)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:133)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy83.count(Unknown Source)
    at com.test.startup.StartupDbDataInit.onApplicationInit(StartupDbDataInit.java:38)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:365)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:310)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:133)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.Session.getFlushMode()Lorg/hibernate/FlushMode;
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.prepareFlushMode(HibernateJpaDialect.java:187)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.beginTransaction(HibernateJpaDialect.java:173)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:380)
    ... 46 more
```

Dependency:tree

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Monitor 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The artifact aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.5.4 has been relocated to org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.5.4
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ Monitor ---
[WARNING] The artifact aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.5.4 has been relocated to org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.5.4
[INFO] Monitor:Monitor:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.3.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.3.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.3.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.3.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:4.3.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.3.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.3.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:1.10.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:1.12.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:4.2.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:4.2.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:4.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:4.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:4.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:5.2.2.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:5.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.20.0-GA:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jta_1.1_spec:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.2.2.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss:jandex:jar:2.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- javax.enterprise:cdi-api:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |     +- javax.el:el-api:jar:2.2:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.jboss.spec.javax.interceptor:jboss-interceptors-api_1.1_spec:jar:1.0.0.Beta1:compile
[INFO] |     +- javax.annotation:jsr250-api:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |     \- javax.inject:javax.inject:jar:1:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:5.3.0.Alpha1:compile
[INFO] |  \- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] +- org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.5.4:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.21:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.21:runtime
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.7.21:runtime
[INFO] +- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17:runtime
[INFO] +- commons-dbcp:commons-dbcp:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-pool:commons-pool:jar:1.5.4:compile
[INFO] +- javax.transaction:jta:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:3.1.0:provided
[INFO] +- javax.servlet.jsp:jsp-api:jar:2.2:compile
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:jstl:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.jsoup:jsoup:jar:1.7.2:compile
[INFO] +- javax.mail:mail:jar:1.4.7:compile
[INFO] |  \- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] \- javax.mail:javax.mail-api:jar:1.5.5:compile
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.467 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-08-16T12:18:23+03:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 13M/245M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [spring-orm-4.2.6 incompatible to hibernate-orm-5.2.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37610839/spring-orm-4-2-6-incompatible-to-hibernate-orm-5-2-0)

Comment: @NeilStockton I`m using xml configuration and spring 4.3 so it isnot Dup..

Comment: It is the EXACT SAME ERROR. NoSuchMethodError is clear enough ... inconsistent libs. XML has nothing to do with that

Comment: Add the full stacktrace. The stacktrace you posted has nothing to do with the line you provided at the beginning

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The module `hibernate-entitymanager` was removed in Hibernate 5.2.0 and the functionality was moved to `hibernate-core`. So you can just remove the hibernate-entitymanager dependency (and while you're on it, use the latest version 5.2.2):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.2.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

If you still have the same error afterwards, it might be, that another dependency still depends on an older version of `hibernate-entitymanager`, which causes then conflicts. In this case, add the hibernate-entitymanager again with the newest version:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.2.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Also since spring-data-jpa 1.10.2 depends on spring-orm 4.2.6, you should add the explicit dependency to spring-orm with the correct version:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I tried it and still the same error :/ even that i do "maven clean" is still the same

Comment: Can you please run "mvn dependency:tree" and add the output to your post? If the post is too long, you can remove all examples except pom.xml

Comment: Also have you made sure, that the Eclipse classpath was updated properly after changing the pom.xml? You seem to use the maven-eclipse-plugin, which is not supported anymore, so you should use the Maven integrations from Eclipse (m2e), which take care of that.

Comment: I need to go: maven > build.. > dependency:tree > run? right?   And what do you mean m2e? just removing the plugin?

Comment: So you already use the Maven integrations in Eclipse. Then you can remove the maven-eclipse-plugin from the pom.xml, since you don't seem to call it explicitly. And yes, that's the way to run dependency:tree in your case.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick answers and patience :) It solved!!

Comment: Directly adding the spring-orm dependency with the proper version solved this for me.

Answer (score 2):

You use incompatible libs. 
The API has changed in hibernate 5:

> FlushModeType getFlushMode()
>
> For users of the Hibernate native APIs, we've had to rename this
>   method as defined by Hibernate historically because the JPA contract
>   defines a method of the same name, but returning the JPA FlushModeType
>   rather than Hibernate's FlushMode.

Comment: So what you suggest me to do? It is wotking in the sam config in diffrent project :/

Comment: @Guyb Why you use different hibernate Versions in your pom?

Comment: I readed that this versions of hibernate supprot the spring 4.3.x version. And Full stack trace is at the end og the question.. Is that you mean?

Comment: @Guyb Do you see the line `Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.Session.getFlushMode()Lorg/hibernate/FlushMode;` in the stacktrace at the end? I am not. So it can not be the full tsacktrace

Comment: @Guyb can you try to remove `hibernate-entitymanager` see maven comment `(deprecated Use Hibernate Core Instead) Hibernate JPA Support `

Comment: Do you mean from pox.xml?

Comment: @Guyb Yes i mean from the POM

Comment: @Guyb You mean same exception?

Comment: Yes it is the same

Comment: You rclean and rebuild your app after changing?

Answer (score 0):

The following combination works fine for me:

```
<properties>
  <project.mysql.connector.version>5.1.30</project.mysql.connector.version>
  <project.hibernate.version>5.2.2.Final</project.hibernate.version>
  <project.spring.orm.version>4.3.3.RELEASE</project.spring.orm.version>
  <project.spring.data.jpa.version>1.10.3.RELEASE</project.spring.data.jpa.version>
</properties>


<dependency>
   <groupId>mysql</groupId>
   <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
   <version>${project.mysql.connector.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
   <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
   <version>${project.hibernate.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
   <version>${project.spring.data.jpa.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
   <version>${project.spring.orm.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

But, while using the MULTI-TENANCY (currently configured for SCHEMA), it is not able to create the tables before trying to insert data and throws exception that table is not present. I really don't want to use the sql import as that takes away all the benefit of automatic schema management.

Answer (score 0):

This looks as a Jar conflict.
I am using `Spring Framework 4.3.5.RELEASE` version and I downgrade hibernate to `hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final`.
It works for me.