# spring 4.2.4.RELEASE + hibernate 5.2.4.Final java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: spring, hibernate

my DAO code:

```
public class UserDaoImpl extends HibernateDaoSupport implements UserDao {
    public List<User> findAll() {
        return (List<User>) this.getHibernateTemplate().find("from User");
    }
}
```

when i run it lead a error like this:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.Session.createQuery(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/hibernate/Query;

at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate$29.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:866)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate$29.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:863)
```

what should i do to correct this error?

Comment: can you post your maven pom.xml or jars that you are using

Comment: Could you post more lines in the stacktrace (at least up to your DAO call) ?

Comment: @kuhajeyan the pom.xml at [paren_pom](https://github.com/BeeDance/ssh_parent/blob/master/pom.xml)  and [dao_pom](https://github.com/BeeDance/ssh_parent/blob/master/ssh_dao/pom.xml)

Comment: @Thierry the whole stacktarce at [error](https://github.com/BeeDance/ssh_parent/blob/master/errorNote)

Comment: how do you run the application?

Comment: @kuhajeyan this is my test [code](https://github.com/BeeDance/ssh_parent/blob/master/ssh_dao/src/test/java/UserTest.java)

Answer (score 2):

Seems something to with the compatibility of spring and hibernate spring 4.2.x is not going well with hibernate version greater than. 5.1.x

change your version

```
  <hibernate.version>5.1.0.Final</hibernate.version>
```

which should allow you to work with your current spring version.

Probably you should log ticket in spring jira as well.

Check : [spring-orm-4.2.6 incompatible to hibernate-orm-5.2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37610839/spring-orm-4-2-6-incompatible-to-hibernate-orm-5-2-0) and [SPR-14327](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-14327)